# Disciples state of sin prior to the crucifixion/resurrection

Tags: sin

How did the disciples receive forgiveness of sins prior to jesus' atoning death?

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE. This is a site for understanding the Bible. If you have a specific passage in mind with this question, please edit your question to include it and flag for moderator review to have it re-opened. Otherwise without a Bible passage, this is more of a theological question and off-topic for our site. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My answer will apply to this question as well.  "How did anyone receive forgiveness of sins prior to Jesus' atoning death?"  God saves, and from what I see in the scriptures, has always saved people by grace through faith in Him.  Post death and resurrection the faith is specifically faith in Jesus' death and resurrection for our sins.  This is the most quoted verse in the New Testament: Gen. 15:6 Then he believed in the Lord; and He reckoned it to him as righteousness.

Before the law of Moses, before circumcision, Abraham was saved by believing God, specifically in Him and His words.  The disciples faith in Jesus = faith in God.

Now, if Jesus wouldn't have died and rose again, we would, including the disciples and Abe, all be dead in our sins.  The application of Jesus blood was applied to Abraham's account backwards, the disciples accounts current, in the same way Jesus blood was applied to believers accounts today in His future.